# What's the simplest/cheapest coffee maker that can make a good latte automatically?

Tags: coffee-machines, milk

I would like to buy a machine that can make me a cup of good latte/cappuccino in the morning. There are dozens of options on the market: from capsule-based machines to huge expensive pro coffee makers, so it's very hard to choose.

What is the simplest/cheapest machine (in terms of long-term costs) that can make a good latte automatically? By 'automatically' I mean a system that delivers a cup of coffee with a press of a button, rather than having to skim milk separately.

Comment: Just the press of a button? Or do you take the milk from the fridge first (and put it back there later)? What quality of coffee do you require? I remember very cheap powders to which you add hot water that make a decent cup. It's not fresh, it has no real foam (or even milk for that matter), consistency and taste were okay, price was great. Steaming milk separately with real steam and making an espresso separately using proper pressure with fresh(ly roasted and ground) beans is the best but more expensive and more work. (unless you find someone to do it for you)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you that do some research on superautomatic machines, there are plenty of options and we can discuss for years on which one is better (or worse).

You have to consider your budget I'll say. There are many machines, many brands, many functionalities, etc... But you'll never produce a *great latte*, because no machine (someone correct me please) can steam milk automatically with the consistency of a human barista. Most of automatic machines only froth the milk.

Maybe if you could present us more options or specify your constraints, we can be more useful.